# How to save data from HTML to XML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have seen this question answered elsewhere, although the text book I am reading is teaching me differently from other examples I have seen on the net.

I would like to continue learning the way this text book is teaching me, as I am finding it easy to learn and follow.

I am attempting to use a HTML form to save just a simple name and message. I then use Javascript and PHP to save this to an XML document.

I am using all my code on a server (MAMP on my mac), as the text book states. Although, it still refuses to work. I know for sure that all my code is correct, and is copied from the text book word for word.

I have tested in IE, FF and Chrome. If anyone has any ideas why it is not working, it would be greatly appreciated!

I have pasted my index.htm in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/KsjxLjgj

The XML and PHP is posted here since it is super simple.

PHP:

```
<?php
//file_put_contents("messages.xml", "<?xml version=".$_POST['<?xml_version']);
file_put_contents("messages.xml", file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
OK
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages>
  <message>
   <text>
   <![CDATA[Some words that are the content of the message.]]>
   </text>
   <user>user 1</user>
   <date>10 MArch 2011</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <text>
   <![CDATA[Some words that are the content of the message.]]>
   </text>
   <user>user 2</user>
   <date>17 July 2008</date>
  </message>
</messages>
```